# Invalid Build path for driver creation

Tags: fedora, kernel, drivers

I wanted to create a simple Hello world driver as in here: [Page2](http://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch02.pdf) and compile it with Makefile:

```
obj-m := hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

But I got:

> make[1](http://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch02.pdf): *** /lib/modules/4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.

Which is logic, since *build* is a link to `/usr/src/kernels/4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64` and my `/usr/src` directory is empty. **But** kernel-devel is installed: `rpm -qa|grep kernel`:

```
kernel-headers-4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-modules-4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-core-4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-devel-4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-modules-extra-4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-modules-extra-4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-core-4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64
libreport-plugin-kerneloops-2.6.4-1.fc23.x86_64
abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.8.0-2.fc23.x86_64
kernel-4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64
kernel-modules-4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64
```

And I read that these packages might have been stored in `/usr/include` and when I try to install them, it of course keep saying that they are already installed.

**Question:** What should I do, makefile or installation, to properly compile my hello.c to hello.ko ?

I have Fedora 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so for me worked upgrading/installing kernel and all kernel-X modules.
After that a kernel (propriate version) directory appeared in `/usr/src/kernels/`